# Accordion feature for Prototype JavaScript Framework

Tags: javascript, magento

I am looking at implementing an accordion feature within the admin area of my Magento site.

What would be my best solution to get this done.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? What have you done so far?

Comment: I am displaying an area of content within an options page, I would like this area to be hidden from the user, until they toggle to display. Does this make sense?

Comment: I know what an accordion is. I don't see a specific question about any code. What have you done so far?

Comment: @cookiemonster seems to me he's looking for potential solutions to building an accordion in prototype? We all start somewhere...

Comment: @Tisch: We all start by doing research and trying something... well, most of us.

Comment: @cookiemonster is it not apparent that I had researched but not found a solution, hence me posting my question on here.

Comment: Correct, it is not apparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As much of a pain Magento can be, this feature is already built in so there is no need for any 3rd party plugins.

Trawling through the admin area I was able to find one already in use:

`System -> Configuration -> General`

Here you will see sections such as 'Countries Options' & 'States Options'.

The markup for these is as follows:

```
<div class="entry-edit-head collapseable">
    <a id="general_country-head" href="#" onclick="Fieldset.toggleCollapse('general_country', ''); return false;" class="">Countries Options</a>
</div>

<fieldset class="config collapseable" id="general_country">
    <!-- Code -->
</fieldset>
```

With a bit of styling (or remove the class 'entry-edit-head' from the parent div) you will be able to remove the blue header, leaving a nice simple accordion!

Comment: Bish bash bosh great answer many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try either of the following:

- https://github.com/tvdeyen/accordion
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-simple-intelligent-accordion-effect-using-prototype-and-scriptaculous--net-34

I'd recommend getting a JSfiddle setup first before applying it to the Magento admin area. When I get a bit of time later, I'll have a go and post the JSFiddle with an example in it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Agreed, hence saying that I'll edit later to provide an example.

Comment: Don't post an answer until you're ready to answer. And don't make your answer entirely dependant on other sites like jsFiddle.

Comment: Sir, yes sir! I'll take inspiration from your greatness.

Comment: On a serious note though... loads of people answer with JSFiddles, what is so wrong with that (other than it can go down, but so can any website)

Comment: Nothing wrong with posting a link (jsFiddle or other) as long as all the relevant information is directly in your answer. Answers on StackOverflow shouldn't be dependant on the existence of an external page.